# Trusted 2008 RDP publisher thumbprint failure

Tags: ssl-certificate, remote, remote-desktop-services

Server 2008 R2, Windows 7.  I'm trying to use group policy to specify the thumbprints of a trusted RDP publisher (me).  I've followed the msdn instructions for getting and setting the thumbprint and yet it's not working.  I used the user policy to set it, and logged off and back on again with the user, restarted for good measure.  It's still prompting me when I open the RDP file.

I'm including a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb8s5.png) that proves that I'm picking up the policy and the correct thumbprint is in there.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

MSDN: hxxp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771261%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Is the CRL specified in the cert available and current? You'll get this error if it can not be checked, or is not current.

Comment: Yes, it was issued by my local CA.